# Error on Constructing Struct in C#

Tags: c#, struct, default-constructor, automatic-properties

Sorry for the genericness of the title, I really don't understand the error that I'm receiving.

So I'm following [this tutorial on C#](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jKAIR-LrZOI), and I'm up to the section "Structs & Memory Management".

Around the 5:30 mark, he begins creating a `Color` Struct, so I follow along, line for line. All the while, his code shows no errors.

**My Errors**

Mine does, however. Four of them, to be precise:

1) `Error 1: Backing field for automatically implemented property 'Color.R' must be fully assigned before control is returned to the caller. Consider calling the default constructor from a constructor initializer.`

Errors 2 & 3 are the same as 1, except replace `Color.R` with `Color.G` & `Color.B`.

Finally, error 4:

`The 'this' object cannot be used before all of its fields are assigned to.`

**Code**

Here's my code for my Color struct (again, I'm struggling to notice any difference between my code and the tutorial master's code):

```
public struct Color
{
    public byte R { get; private set; }
    public byte G { get; private set; }
    public byte B { get; private set; }

    public Color(byte red, byte green, byte blue)
    {
        R = red;
        G = green;
        B = blue;
    }

    public static Color Red
    {
        get { return new Color(255, 0, 0); }
    }

    public static Color Green
    {
        get { return new Color(0, 255, 0); }
    }

    public static Color Blue
    {
        get { return new Color(0, 0, 255); }
    }

    public static Color Black
    {
        get { return new Color(0, 0, 0); }
    }

    public static Color White
    {
        get { return new Color(255, 255, 255); }
    }
}
```

I'm totally new to C#, but have some PHP experience, so I'm a little confused as to what exactly is happening here. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Structs` can only really use the default constructor to be built initially. Change your constructor to call the default:

```
public Color(byte red, byte green, byte blue)
    : this() 
{
    this.R = red;
    this.G = green;
    this.B = blue;
}
```

By calling `this` you are using the default constructor and then setting the private values on that particular instance.  If this was a `class` instead of a `struct` your code would have worked without issue.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for being helpful.